# Get UsagePlanID AWS CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I have created an API Key, an UsagePlan and while creating gUsagePlanKey, I need ApiKeyID(ApiKey.getKeyId()) and UsagePlanId(I am not sure how to get that).

I am trying to fetch UsagePlanID from UsagePlan.getLogicalId() which is wrong, I am not sure how to fetch it. I am using CDK for java.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for very basic question. AttrId is the ID of the Usage Plan can be fetched through GetAttributeID() method.